# Vectorized subsetting of matrices with varying index length

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization

I am trying to convert the rows of the matrices below into indices to subset from another matrix. The first matrix would generate four indices to be used for subsetting from a matrix called `data`, shown at the bottom. The second matrix would generate six indices, each of length two, and so on.

```
library(gtools) # library for combinations()
matrix(match(combinations(n=4,r=1,v=LETTERS[1:4]),LETTERS),ncol=1)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4

matrix(match(combinations(n=4,r=2,v=LETTERS[1:4]),LETTERS),ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4


matrix(match(combinations(n=4,r=3,v=LETTERS[1:4]),LETTERS),ncol=3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    2    4
[3,]    1    3    4
[4,]    2    3    4

matrix(match(combinations(n=4,r=4,v=LETTERS[1:4]),LETTERS),ncol=4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4


data <- matrix(rnorm(16,0),ncol=4)
data[,1]
data[,2]
data[,3]
data[,4]
```

The second matrix would generate indices to be used like:

```
data[,c(1,2)]
data[,c(1,3)]
data[,c(1,4)]
data[,c(2,3)]
```

etc.

What would a generic, vectorized function look like to accomplish the above for varying `n`?

Comment: Please, include the packages you are using. Where `combinations` is from?

Comment: Updated. `combinations` is from `library(gtools)`.

Comment: You can try `combn(1:4,n,FUN=function(x) data[,x],simplify=FALSE)` for instance. Set `n<-2` for instance, run the line above and see if it is your desired output.

Comment: That might work -- it returns a list of matrices. How would I sum the rows of each matrix in the list, and calculate that rowsum mod 2?

Comment: Try `lapply(reslist,function(x) rowSums(x %% 2))` where `reslist` is the result of the `combn` command above. Or in one line `combn(1:4,n,FUN=function(x) rowSums(data[,x]) %% 2)`.

Comment: @nicola both of your solutions worked well (I used the two-liner since it is easier for someone else to understand.) Do you want to post it as a formal answer so I can choose it?